# Best way to set up cloudant backup/restore

Tags: couchdb, replication, database-backups, cloudant, backup-strategies

I have just got to the point of having enough data in my cloudant DB that it would be an issue if I lost it so am now looking into what is a good/reliable(/free!) method of getting regular backups of my data.

I've looked at the documentation and its recommending using backup via replication (https://docs.cloudant.com/backup-guide-using-replication.html)

The method here seems to be:
1. Full backup via replication 1 day
2. Incremental backups to different backups on subsequent days

There seem to be 2 drawbacks here:
1. Backing up is still in cloudant so im paying full price vs being able to move it off to a cheaper alternative for long term storage
2. It isnt clear how the method described would actually work when you cycle the replication (for example, if the 'full' replication was on a monday, then incremental every other day, when you get to the full backup the following monday its no longer possible to restore to any day previously e.g. sunday, saturday, friday etc)

I've seen other solutions described such as installing couchdb on EC2, replicating to that and then taking nightly backups into amazon glacier (glacier is cheap but seems like EC2 couchdb instance is an annoying expense there).

Does anyone have a recommendation here?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a dump to file using couch_backup and store on Object Storage which is cost effective. See https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/object-storage-cloudant-backup/ for more details